# How to search for special characters in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I need to perform a text search in Outlook e-mails subject and/or body, looking for two-character string that represent a code in our business.
The problem is that these codes can assume forms like '@B', '£Z', etc.  One of the characters could be a symbol.

For example, when I try to search for a string like '#R', Outlook is giving me lots of results with subject starting with 'R'.  It seems like special characters are ignored when specifying text to search for.

I tried surrounding with quotation marks or apostrophes, no way.  I tried escaping the special character as '/#' '\#' and '&hash;' but nothing changes either.

How can I search symbols in the e-mail subject?
Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please [take a look](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/389):

> If the word starts with a special character, then Instant Search will
>   ignore this special characters as the index of Instant Search is
>   word-based only. In that case, you’ll need to use Advanced Find
>   instead.
>   When you want to include words which start with special characters in
>   your search query, you’ll have to use the Advanced tab of Advanced
>   Find.

Open Advanced Find (shortcut key: CTRL+SHIFT+F)
    Select the Advanced tab
    Create the following search query
        Field: Subject
        Condition: contains
        Value:

[image]

Of course you’ll replace  with your own search phrase containing your special characters.

Comment: That worked fine! Well, it requires a bit more input than standard search but don't see other ways :)  thanks.

Comment: NOTE: If you want to search subfolders with this (for example, an "archive" folder within the main inbox folder), you need to click "Browse" in the top right of the Advanced Find window posted by duDE, then check the box in the bottom-left that says "Search subfolders".  Search me why that's disabled by default . . .

Comment: Doesn't work. I used the "Advanced Find" tool to search for email subjects containing a square bracket in the subecjt, it doesn't bring anything back even when there's dozens of emails with a square bracket in the subject.

Comment: Italian users should type CTRL+SHIFT+T to enter the advanced search. I suppose with other languages it's the same, just translate "Find" in your local language and pick the first letter.

Comment: It is not finding emails with %k in the subject, but just emails containing k

Comment: @KAE I've just checked this, use the "Advanced" tab, it should do the job. When you do it in the "Messages" tab it's apparently ignoring the '%'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, searching for special characters seems like a lot of work.  We are able to do regular searches for things such as d4 , smith7 , h25  so I think I will use codes that are strictly alphanumeric in the subject lines and bodies of emails  to make searches easier.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1170989)