# Why does Outlook search ignore underscore character?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I'd like to search for all Outlook messages containing the phrase "Computer_Data" but not "Computer Data". But when I use the regular or [Advanced find](https://superuser.com/questions/1027911/how-to-search-for-special-characters-in-outlook) function using "Computer_Data", I get hits for "Computer Data", "Computer*Data", as well as "Computer_Data"; the underscore character is ignored. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Why? because the search is alphanumerical (a-z, 0-9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I tested in outlook 365 client. When I search by using Advanced Find (Search tools>Advanced Find>Advanced>click Browse… and choose the folder>under Define more criteria, choose the Field, condition and type Value: ***Computer_Data*** >Add to List>Find Now), the message containing this field can be displayed in search results, as shown in the following figure.
[image]

Please check whether your search steps are the same as above.

Comment: Thank you for the screenshot. I guess I can't insert an image in a comment, but I am able to search as you indicate and just retrieve "Computer_Data".